# Each 15 minutes i need calculating amount using Java

Tags: java

i am creating a simple Intenet cafe management System using Java.this my final year project every thing gone fine. at the final stage of project i faced the problem of when person sit on the computer time is started it is working fine i attached sceen shot below. each 15mins i need calculating amount 50 i don't how to do it. what i tried so far i attached below.

[image]

```
 public gg() {
        initComponents();
         TimeStart();
        T.start();

    }

    public void TimeStart()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread()
  {
      public void run()
          {
             while(true)
          {
             DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
             Date date = new Date();
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             txttime.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));  
             try {
              Thread.sleep(1);
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(gg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }    
          }
          }
  };
  t.start();

 int sec=0; int min=0; int hour=0; 

    int Cumvalue = 0;
    Timer T = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sec++;
            txtsec.setText(":" + sec);      
            if(sec==60)
            {
                sec=0;
                 txtsec.setText(":" +0);
                 min++;
                   txtmin.setText(":" +min);

                   if(min >= 15)
              {
                    Cumvalue += 50;

                   txtam.setText(String.valueOf(Cumvalue));
              }


              if(hour==60)
              {
                  min=0;
                  txtmin.setText(":" + 0);
                  hour++;
                  txthour.setText(":" +hour);
              }  

            }  





        }
    });
```

i tried like this way

```
 if(min >= 15)
              {
                    Cumvalue += 50;

                   txtam.setText(String.valueOf(Cumvalue));
              }
```

it didnt not work

Comment: `if(hour==60)` doesn't look right. did you mean `if (min == 60)` ?

Comment: yes ..............       . then how to write it proper way to calculating the amount

Comment: "remember" the timestamp when you were started, on each iteration take the current timestamp, calculate the difference in millis, and properly format that time? delegating the suming (`CumValue`) as well as tracking total usage time to a new `UsageTime` class might be a good idea.

Comment: can you write the code i can easy to understand

Comment: You need to revise your code in `TimeStart` thread - you let the thread sleep for just 1 millisecond, thus, you try to create DateFormatter and output the time ~1000 times per second!  This does not seem to be right.

Comment: can you write the code i can easy to understand

Comment: Do not use Date and Calendar, use the new java.time API. Thread.sleep's parameter is in milliseconds, not seconds. Using raw threads with Swing is questionable. It might be better to use a SwingWorker.

Comment: how to work i don't know

Comment: can you write the code i can easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to check if the minutes are divisible by 15.

```
 if(min%15 == 0)
              {
                    Cumvalue += 50;

                   txtam.setText(String.valueOf(Cumvalue));
              }
```

Comment: it didn't work it sir. each 15 minutures amount should increment .only  increment by first 15 mins only this code worked